# Fixing this so it works if the element is not on the current page

Tags: jquery, nav, sticky

I found this fix for a sticky header and it works great, but on some of my pages the '.menu' class doesn't exist. I'm wondering how I can adjust this to only run if the element is on the current page. When it's not there I am getting this error message.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" because .menu isn't there

```
// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD

Comment: If I understand correctly, in some pages the 'menu' class does not exist. Am I correct? Are you getting error in the first line of code?

Comment: Just wrap in `if( $(.menu).length ) { ... }`. You should also optimize your code, you should not search for elements in each 10milisecond interval. Also, should not be in intervals, but on `window.scroll` event.

Answer (score 2):

You could just check if `.menu` exists before executing `stickIt()`.

like so:

```
if ($('.menu').length) {
    // Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
    $('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        stickIt();
    });
}
```

You should also replace your `setInterval` with a `.scroll()`. It's certainly not more elegant, but might motivate you to optimize what you have.

here the edited pen:
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxVNKb)